# nlohmann json insert object in array

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

The json file is:

```
{
  "vis.DataSet": [],
  "backup": []
}
```

I want to insert 2 objects {a=1,b=2,c=3} and {a=4,b=5} to "vis.DataSet" key.

Then the json become as

```
{
  "vis.DataSet": [
  {
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2,
    "c" : 3
  },
  {
    "a" : 4,
    "b" : 5
  }
  ],
  "backup": []
}
```

Here is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
json srcJson = R"(
{
  "vis.DataSet": [],
  "backup": []
}
)"_json;

json objJson1 = R"(
{
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "c" : 3
}
)"_json;

json bojJson2 = R"(
{
  "a" : 4,
  "b" : 5
}
)"_json;

srcJson["vis.DataSet"].push_back[objJson1];
srcJson["vis.DataSet"].push_back[objJson2];
```

Comment: What do you mean `with but it doesn't work.`? The shown code does not compile. Is your question about the compile errors? If so, you have to include those in the question and explain what you don't understand about them.

Comment: You should include the exact comiplation error you get (as text) in your question.

Answer (score 2):

In lines like this:

```
srcJson["vis.DataSet"].push_back[objJson1];
```

You attempt to call the `push_back` method with **square brackets** (`[]`) instead of normal **parenthesis** (`()`).
Therefore you get compilation errors.

You need to change it to:

```
//------------------------------V--------V
srcJson["vis.DataSet"].push_back(objJson1);
```

The same applies to the second attempt to call `push_back`.